# How do you change the display name when sending emails via Amazon SES in Django?

Tags: python, django, amazon-ses

Currently I have a working implementation of sending emails with Amazon SES in Django.

My setup looks like this. In settings.py I have:

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'email-smtp....'
EMAIL_PORT = 25
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'my-email-host-user'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'my-email-host-password'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

In my view I have:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib import messages
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage

def index(request):
    email_message = EmailMessage('This is a title', 'This is a message body', 'FromEmail@example.com', ['ToEmail@example.com'])
    email_message.send()
    return HttpResponse("You just sent an email message.")
```

When I open the message I get this in the header:

```
FromEmail@example.com via amazonses.com
```

I would like to customize this so that I can do something like this:

```
UserFirstName UserLastName via amazonses.com
```

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I doubt that you can, but you should be able to use from addresses like this:

```
email_message = EmailMessage('This is a title', 'This is a message body', 'UserFirstName UserLastName <FromEmail@example.com>', ['ToEmail@example.com'])
```

which should result in email clients displaying the from address like this:

```
UserFirstName UserLastName <FromEmail@example.com>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I didn't mean to leave out the <FromEmail@example.com> from my example. Thanks!

Comment: in the from section I use settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, if I set display name as shown above the email is not sent. What should I do?